# VBA global frame array

Tags: arrays, vba, controls, global, frame

unfortunately I was not able to answer my question with the help of Google.

I created a Userform with a frame which contains different controls (Textbox, Combobox, Listbox, Label).
Usually the inputs are saved directly to a workbook after the user presses the OK button.

But there is one special situation, where I want the user to fill in several of these Input Userforms one after another and save all the contents of the Userforms at last.
Therefore I created a global Object-Array where I saved the Input-Frames of each Userform, the user filled in.

At the end I wanted to go through all these frames and its controls and save the contents in one step.
My already existing save function uses a frame as input, so I wanted to loop through my frame array.

Here is my example code:
(conArr is a global Object Array variable)

```
Public Sub btnOK_Click()
    conArrRow = 0
    ReDim Preserve conArr(conArrRow)
    Set conArr(conArrRow) = frmData.frameDataInput
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

After the Userform is unloaded I get back to the main code.

```
For Each ctl In conArr(0).Controls
     MsgBox ctl.Name
Next
```

Here I get the error at line: `For Each ctl In conArr(0).Controls`

```
Microsoft Visual Basic
Run time error -2147418113 (8000ffff)
Automation error 
Catastrophic failure.
```

I guess the problem occurs because the form with its frame is already unloaded and does not exist anymore. If I put the part of the main code directly to the end of btnOK_Click it works.

I appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to store the control values, copy the control values. Like you have discovered, controls do not exist without a form. You could create several instances of the form, hide them all and store references to that, but I would encourage you not to.

Comment: Which application are you calling this code from? Is it Excel, or Word or what?

Comment: It is Excel, i am using. Well, i hoped I can use the whole Controls because i need different values like value, tiptext, listbox entries,  etc. It would be much easier to use the whole control objects. Is there no other way?